# Logical grouping of operator with Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I cant seem to figure out how to write this query using the Neo4jClient

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE (n.Id="1ef17d65-492e-4c0d-aa79-13065edd37f2" AND n.CaseType="NaturalPerson") OR (n.Id="a5c143d4-0306-4057-a96f-e39c5c50eb22" AND n.CaseType="NaturalPerson")
RETURN n
```

If i write the query like this

```
this.client.Cypher.Match("(n)")
                .Where("f.Id=\"1ef17d65-492e-4c0d-aa79-13065edd37f2\"")
                .AndWhere("n.CaseType=\"NaturalPerson\"")
                .OrWhere("f.Id=\"1ef17d65-492e-4c0d-aa79-13065edd37f2\"")
                .AndWhere("n.CaseType=\"NaturalPerson\"")
                .Return((n, r) => n.As<T>());
```

The following query is generated, but it does not have the parentheses '(' ')' which logicly group the two and clauses

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE f.Id="1ef17d65-492e-4c0d-aa79-13065edd37f2"
AND n.CaseType="NaturalPerson"
OR f.Id="1ef17d65-492e-4c0d-aa79-13065edd37f2"
AND n.CaseType="NaturalPerson"
RETURN n AS Node, r AS Metadata
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either do:

```
.Where("n.Id='1ef17d65-492e-4c0d-aa79-13065edd37f2' AND n.CaseType='NaturalPerson')
.OrWhere("n.Id='a5c143d4-0306-4057-a96f-e39c5c50eb22' AND n.CaseType='NaturalPerson'")
```

or, you could put it all in one `.Where`

But, if it was me, I would do:

```
.Where("n.CaseType = 'NaturalPerson')
.AndWhere("n.Id IN ['1ef17d65-492e-4c0d-aa79-13065edd37f2','a5c143d4-0306-4057-a96f-e39c5c50eb22']
```

And I would definitely be using parameters like so:

```
var ids = new [] {'a5c143d4-0306-4057-a96f-e39c5c50eb22', '1ef17d65-492e-4c0d-aa79-13065edd37f2'};
var caseType = "NaturalPerson";

this.client.Cypher.Match("(n)")
    .Where("n.CaseType = $caseTypeParam")
    .AndWhere("n.Id IN $idsParam")
    .WithParam("caseTypeParam", caseType)
    .WithParam("idsParam", ids")
    /*.. etc..*/
```

Comment: Thanks, i ended up doing it this way it just felt wrong i thought there might have been a way to do it using the fluid query linq like syntax (i forget the exact name for it)
*Also i am using the parameters i just left them out for brevity 

Comment: It would also be great if this were in the documentation somewhere, it took me ages to actually try this way of doing it.